# Bash script to add constant to file names

Tags: bash

I need a bash script to rename the files in a directory. The names have the format `<name>_<number>` (eg `bob_12`, `alice_233`). The script must change them to `<name>_<number+k>` (eg, if k=20, `bob_32`, `alice_253`). Can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ ls
alice_253  bob_32
$ k=20
$ for old in *; do new=${old%_*}_$((${old#*_}+k)); mv "$old" "$new"; done
$ ls
alice_273  bob_52
```

This is just an example though. It won't work properly if there are files whose names have:

- dash as the first character,
- any number of underscores but one,
- non-digit characters at the righthand side of the underscore,
- a zero immediately following the underscore.

If we wanted to cover those cases as well, assuming filenames may not overlap (e.g `foo_100` and `foo_120` when `k=20`, in which case we'd need to sort them in reverse order first), we'd do:

```
# handle -foo_123
# skip foo, foo_bar, foo_012,
# and foo_bar_123
k=20
for old in ./*_*; do
  case $old in
    (*_*_*) ;&
    (*_*[!0-9]*) ;&
    (*_0*) continue
  esac
  new=${old%_*}_$((${old#*_}+k))
  mv "$old" "$new"
done
```